# How to take and restore backup with an LTO tape drive in RedHat?

Tags: backup, tape

I can take a backup with an IBM LTO tape drive in RedHat 5 using `mt` and `tar`, but I can't restore it. I can't see previous backup content. Whenever I try to take a backup, I think that the new backup overwrites the one on tape every time.

`mt` command does not work to rewind the tape.

Can someone explain how I should restore and list backup contents from the tape drive?

Comment: Please create one question per topic.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to store more than one archive file on a tape, you can do so by using the nonrewinding tape device filename.

For example:

```
tar cvlpf /dev/nst0 /home
tar cvlpf /dev/nst0 /
```

That should write the `/home` and the `/` into 2 separate files in the tape device.

To access each files after you have created them in the tape, you should use `mt` as `mt` take the following syntax:

```
mt -f device operation [count] [arguments]
```

You should put `fsf` and a number in the `[count]` in order to go to that number file. `bsf` and number is backwards.

So suppose you have written already one file to the tape drive with the above `tar` command, now you should do `#mt -f /dev/tapeDev fsf 1` then issue the second `tar` command (for example you could use the mentioned above command), then `#mt -f /dev/tapeDev offline` in order to rewind and unload the tape.

Always it is good idea to issue the `#mt -f /dev/tapeDev rewind` command before you write anything to it, so that you make sure that you start to write to the start of the tape drive.